# Downloaded jar file corrupted

Tags: java, url, download, corrupt

I've got this code that downloads a .jar file from a specific URL and places it into a specific folder. The jar file downloaded is a mod for a game, meaning that it has to be downloaded and run correctly without being corrupted.

The problem is, each time I try downloading the file, it ends up being corrupted in some way and causing errors when it is loaded.

This is my download code:

```
final static int size=1024;

public static void downloadFile(String fAddress, String localFileName, String destinationDir, String modID) {
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    URLConnection  uCon = null;

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        URL Url;
        byte[] buf;
        int ByteRead,ByteWritten=0;
        Url= new URL(fAddress);
        outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new
                FileOutputStream(destinationDir+"/"+localFileName));

        uCon = Url.openConnection();
        is = uCon.getInputStream();
        buf = new byte[size];
        while ((ByteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
            ByteWritten += ByteRead;
        }
        System.out.println("Downloaded Successfully.");
        System.out.println("File name:\""+localFileName+ "\"\nNo ofbytes :" + ByteWritten);
        System.out.println("Writing info file");
        WriteInfo.createInfoFile(localFileName, modID);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
            outStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong with this code?

Comment: A side note: coding convention says variable names should start with a small letter.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with this code. In what way is the downloaded file corrupted? (Wrong length, bytes substituted, ..) Can you be sure that it's not the server that's corrupting the file?

Comment: I know that the file is fine on the server because I've tried to manually download and install it using my web browser. When I tried that, it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem but you should flush your buffer at the end.

```
outStream.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

your code look like quite right; try this

```
public static void downloadFromUrl(String srcAddress, String userAgent, String destDir, String destFileName, boolean overwrite) throws Exception
   {
      InputStream is = null;
      FileOutputStream fos = null;

      try
      {
         File destFile = new File(destDir, destFileName);
         if(overwrite && destFile.exists())
         {
            boolean deleted = destFile.delete();
            if (!deleted)
            {
               throw new Exception(String.format("d'ho, an immortal file %s", destFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
         }

         URL url = new URL(srcAddress);
         URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

         if(userAgent != null)
         {
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
         }

         is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
         fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

         byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

         int len, totBytes = 0;
         while((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
         {
            totBytes += len;
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
         }

         System.out.println("Downloaded successfully");
         System.out.println(String.format("File name: %s - No of bytes: %,d", destFile.getAbsolutePath(), totBytes));
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            if(is != null) is.close();
         }
         finally
         {
            if(fos != null) fos.close();
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Also, I tried this and it didn't quite work. The file downloaded and everything, but it appeared to be corrupted when I tried loading it. I got `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: field_77777_bU` which isn't a problem with the code of the downloaded file, as I can download it fine through my web browser and not get any errors

Comment: some example here: http://home-1.worldonline.nl/~bmc88/java/sbook/045.html
 - ua strings: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent